# update method in adonisjs controller

Tags: javascript, adonis.js

How to update data in the database without creating a new one?

```
async update ({ params, request, response }) {
    const product = await Product.find(params.id)

    product.name = request.input('name')
    product.descr = request.input('descr')
    product.qtd = request.input('qtd')
    product.sub_descr = request.input('sub_descr')
    product.price = request.input('price')

    product.save()

    return response.redirect('/')
  }
```

This code is creating a new instance, the `product.update()` method returns me an error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adonisjs **lucid** supports automatic [inserts & updates](https://adonisjs.com/docs/4.1/lucid#_inserts_updates) - meaning it intelligently updates or inserts a record based on the input.

According to the docs:

> The save method persists the instance to the database, intelligently determining whether to create a new row or update the existing row.

However if you want to perform an update/bulk update you can always build a query as mentioned [here](https://adonisjs.com/docs/4.1/lucid#_bulk_updates).

But the problem you might face it

> Bulk updates don’t execute model hooks.

**Example for Insert/Update:**

```
const User = use('App/Models/User')

const user = new User()
user.username = 'virk'
user.email = 'foo@bar.com'

// Insert
await user.save()

user.age = 22

// Update
await user.save()
```

**Example for Bulk Update:**

```
const User = use('App/Models/User')

await User
  .query()
  .where('username', 'virk')
  .update({ role: 'admin' })
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed explanation, i understand perfectly how it works now